# Adb Transfer Protocol Error. No such file or directory

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-emulator

I tried to run my android app in a emulator using `intelliJ 13`, and I configured the emulator to be a `Nexus 4` running `android 4.4.2` with `ARM` cpu, and I got the follow errors:

```
    Waiting for device.
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd MyAVD0 -netspeed full -netdelay none

    Device connected: emulator-5554
    Device is online: emulator-5554
    Target device: MyAVD0 [emulator-5554]
    Uploading file
local path: C:\Users\daiyue\IdeaProjects\HelloDroid\out\production\HelloDroid\HelloDroid.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.HelloDroid
    Adb Transfer Protocol Error.
    No such file or directory
```

The following is my `manifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.HelloDroid"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

The emulator showed nothing on screen as well, only when I pressed hardware button to switch on the emulator and only 'android' logo showed up and stayed forever.

I built the app using `Android SDK 4.4.2 api`.

So the work around is to delete the `MyAVD0` in `C:\Users\username\.android\avd`, and recreate `MyAVD0` again using `Android AVD Manager`.

Comment: I would suggest that you check if your adb is working properly. I think it seems that the issue is not with the emulator itself, but with the upload of the HelloDroid example. Try to set up an emulator without loading an app and after that push your app onto the emulator with adb - then see if it works.

Comment: @XWaveX so I delete `MySVD0` and create it again and it works, and what is adb? I am using `intelliJ 13` on `Win 7 x64`

Comment: You could also try to add or increase your SD-Storage size in `AVD Manager` for your emulator. (Or perhaps your apk is damaged?)

Comment: ADB (Android Debug Bridge) is used for debugging. You can remotely install apps, browse the storage, log debug messages, etc... http://www.droidwiki.de/Android_Debug_Bridge

Comment: @XWaveX actually MyAVD0 was set to `Nexus 4` with `Android 4.4.2` and then I changed it to `generic QVGA` with `Android 2.2` and this one gave me 'AVD MyAVD0 is not valid: Generic 2.7in QVGA configuration has changed since AVD creation.', So I changed it back to `Nexus 4` with `Android 4.4.2`, and then I encountered the problem described in the post, so I guess it was because the AVD files are corrupted and so a delete may work.