# Adb Transfer Protocol Error. Read-only file system

Tags: android, adb, transfer

I am trying to make a simple android quiz app; however, I got the following error. I am having trouble understanding how and why this happened when I didn't tamper with anything related.

The error is below:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: TestRun [emulator-5554]
Uploading file
    local path: /Users/Spicycurryman/AndroidStudioProjects/GeoQuiz/GeoQiz/build/apk/GeoQiz-debug-unaligned.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz
Adb Transfer Protocol Error.
Read-only file system
```

Comment: Check these links..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100834/adb-transfer-protocol-error-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Well i would recommend to check your adb connection..Try "adb kill-server" and "adb start-server" commands in shell

Answer (score 2):

Based on information from other posts, it seems like your AVD's files are corrupted. A quick fix would be to probably delete that AVD and create a new one with the same specs.